# How to create my own jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie in jQuery, and I am learning how to create my own plugins.

I tried the following code (created by myself):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.myNewFunc= function() {
        alert('you can be a professional ;) continue trying');         
    };
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
         $("#myDiv").myNewFunc();
    });
});
</script>
<button id="myBtn"> click me </button>
<div id ="myDiv" >my div</div>
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).myNewFunc is not a function
```

When I try $("#myDiv").myNewFunc(); outside of the btn.click I can see the alert !

Comment: sure I tried to find how to create a plugin. I tried this link: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: You forgot quotes on `$("#myDiv").myNewFunc();`

Comment: and you are missing the `$` on the button click handler :)

Comment: Okay: after 4 edits your code now works as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/uycmbhrw/ *What* seems to be the problem now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three simple typos are breaking your code:

```
$(#myDiv).myNewFunc();
```

should be:

```
$("#myDiv").myNewFunc();
```

and you are missing a `$` on the function:

```
("#myBtn").click(function(){
```

which should have been:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
```

and you have an extra closing `)` here:

```
$.fn.myNewFunc= function() {
        alert('you can be a professional ;) continue trying');         
    });   <<<=== Typo!!!
```

which should be:

```
$.fn.myNewFunc= function() {
        alert('you can be a professional ;) continue trying');         
    }
```

**Working here:** http://jsfiddle.net/bpfad4jk/1/

Here is a slightly more practical use of your code. You need to return `this` to allow jQuery chaining and also apply your "operation" to all matching elements using `each()`.

e.g.

```
    $.fn.myNewFunc = function() {
        $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).text('you can be a professional ;) continue trying'); 
        });
        return this;
    };
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
         $("#myDiv").myNewFunc();
        $('.myDiv').myNewFunc();
    });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bpfad4jk/2/

Comment: I forget to set them here, but I have them in my code. and always I get the same error.

Comment: @neila: You have two errors (not one) and the JSFiddle works :)

Comment: When I wrote my code here, I forgot the $ and the quotes.
When I try $("#myDiv").myNewFunc(); outside of the btn.click
I can see the alert.

Comment: You still have one typo... `});` should be `};` on the function... Please use the working JSFiddle as an example :)